# Rating stars using CSS (each radio and label inside a div)

Tags: html, css

I need to create a rating stars using css.
I have refered from below link
https://codepen.io/andreacrawford/pen/NvqJXW

But I have different DOM structure.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

.radio-div label {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.radio-div>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
  visibility: visible;
}

.radio-div>input:checked~label {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="radio-div">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star_1">
    <label for="star_1">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-div">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star_2">
    <label for="star_2">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-div">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star_3">
    <label for="star_3">3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-div">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star_4">
    <label for="star_4">4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-div">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star_5">
    <label for="star_5">5</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to achieve star rating functionality in this DOM only.
Please help me.

Comment: So what do you need help with? What do you want to achieve? Where are you stuck, exactly? Is that your CSS above, or is that what you took from the Codepen you linked to?

Comment: Hi David,
I'm trying to achieve like,
If I select 3rd star then 1st , 2nd and 3rd stars should be highlight.

I can't select previous parent's child in css.

Comment: Do you like to use Javascript I can suggest one technique that I use.

Comment: Sorry Asaduzzaman, I can't use JS

Comment: https://codepen.io/md-asaduzzaman-muhid/pen/jOROBdx you can try this pen if works for you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a newly available `:has()` CSS pseudo-class that enables selection of elements containing child elements matching another selector. This will allow to target the specific `.radio-div` that contains a checked radio `input`. Find out if your browser supports this feature: https://caniuse.com/css-has

Also, there is a lot of code handling colors:

- All starts are *active* (green) by default.
- If there is no selected radio input - all starts are *inactive* (black).
- Starts after the one that's selected or hovered are inactive as well.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.radio-div>label {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0;
}

.radio-div>label:before {
  content: '★';
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 14px;
}

.radio-div>label {
  color: green;
}

.wrapper:not(:has(input:checked)) .radio-div>label {
  color: black;
}

.radio-div:has(input:checked)~.radio-div>label {
  color: black;
}

.wrapper:has(label:hover)>div.radio-div>label {
  color: green;
}

.wrapper:hover>div.radio-div:hover~.radio-div>label {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="radio-div">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star_1">
    <label for="star_1">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-div">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star_2">
    <label for="star_2">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-div">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star_3">
    <label for="star_3">3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-div">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star_4">
    <label for="star_4">4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-div">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star_5">
    <label for="star_5">5</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi hedfol,
I can't change the DOM structure. that's my problem.

Comment: @Hariprasath, My mistake. I've just updated the code and explanation to use an original DOM.